# Office 365 list data using jquery

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-online

I am doing azure project in that i want to get list data from sharepoint online(Office365)

So it is possible using jquery?

Comment: You really need to add more detail here. What does "get data" mean? Where are you consuming it? Are you consuming the data within the SharePoint Online site or are you doing it on a non-SharePoint site? Both C-Marius and PirateEric have given possibilities that you could use in either case.

Comment: My jquery run in azure project not in sharepoint site.So it is not possible that without any credentials passing i am getting data from sharepoint online.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to either use REST Api that works for every list in SharePoint, via /_vti_bin/ListData.svc which you could use via $.ajax or $.getJSON calls.

Or use ECMA Client Object Model API in SharePoint 2010 which enables direct access using Javascript to lists. Google-it, many examples available http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/07/19/working-with-the-ecmascript-client-object-model-jsom-in-sharepoint-2010-part-3-nikhil-sachdeva.aspx
Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: I would suggest to go for the REST alternative with jQuery library, which starting v.1.4 supports $.getJSON calls.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to take a look at the [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) library if you're wanting to get to SharePoint list data with jQuery.  It wraps all the web services into easily accessible functions that are a snap to work with.

Since you haven't posted much detail, review the operations and post back with new questions if you have any issues, or post on the spservices discussion board.

Comment: I am able to get list data from local sharepoint server but my question is how i get data from office365.

Comment: SPServices is a JQuery library used for accessing the built in web services of SharePoint. There is no reason I can think of that you cannot use that library to query data in a SharePoint Online list/library.